# Django - strange dictionary behaviour

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to override default error messages in my Django form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    my_errors = {
        'required': 'To pole jest wymagane'
    }
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, error_messages=my_errors.update({'invalid': 'Podaj prawidłowy adres e-mail'}))
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages=my_errors)
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=80, error_messages=my_errors)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=80, error_messages=my_errors)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        User = get_user_model
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
            raise forms.ValidationError('Adres e-mail jest już zajęty')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
```

I can easily change 'required' error message cause it's the same for each field.

But for email field I'd like 'invalid' message to be more specific so I merge the existing dict with a one containing e-mail error message.

But it doesn't work: email field returns to default error messages while the rest of fields uses my error messages.

Please explain why it happens and how to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.update` modifies the dict in-place, and returns `None`.  Therefor, you are passing `error_messages=None` when declaring the `email` field.

Another undesirable side-effect of your code is that `"invalid"` is added to `my_errors`, and that extended `my_errors` is passed when declaring the rest of the fields.

You need to merge the dicts instead of using `update`, like:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    my_errors = {
        'required': 'To pole jest wymagane'
    }
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, error_messages=dict(my_errors, invalid='Podaj prawidłowy adres e-mail'))
    password = forms.CharField(error_messages=my_errors)
    ...
```